# Warning: /root/.curlrc:1: warning: 'ip4' is unknown

Tags: curl, rvm, ruby-on-rails

`Warning: /root/.curlrc:1: warning: 'ip4' is unknown`

This happened after executing:

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`
 and giving the

`0curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.rvm.io port 443: Connection refused`

What does this mean and how do I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this happens due to a IPv6 misconfiguration.

Issue the command `echo ip4 >> ~/.curlrc` this will remember the --ip4 flag for all future curl commands, and should fix the problem.

Source:

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2989